# Windows Command Line: Loop through every word in .txt, output it to newline in new .txt

Tags: windows, text, loops, for-loop, command

I get the feeling this is a pretty simple issue but I'm relatively inexperienced with Windows command line hence the need to ask. In a batch file I'm writing, how would I loop through every separate word in a text file, and output that word to a new line in a new text file?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

sounds like the uber-flexible and least-known-in-DOS FOR command is what you need something like:

```
FOR /f %%A in ('dir /b my_dir\*.csv ^| find /V "summary"') do (
rem do here what you want
)
```

[see this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026773/dos-batch-script-with-for-loop-and-pipe)

EDIT: This shoudl work foe lines in a file. Eaither way... take a look at for. BTW MUCH easier in Powershell.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (myfile) do (
echo do my commands on %%a
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be doing it for all files in a directory though? I only want to do it for one .txt file, and output to another

Comment: Ah remiss of me - easy in Pwoershell. Is that ok or just DOS ??

Comment: I'm trying to do it in just DOS if possible. So far I have this: FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (file1.txt) DO ECHO %%G >> file2.txt

Comment: Hmm you look to be quite close.. did the above help ?? I'll take a look.

Comment: Yeah I've just tried it...it just removes any blank lines in the txt and outputs the rest as before (ie. not one word per line)