# Batch job to check filenames and archive

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, io-redirection

I have a directory where users are saving their excel files that should adhere to a specific naming convention:

```
XX-TestFile.xlsx
```

where `XX` is a variable digit and `-TestFile.xlsx` should always be the same and not change. I'd like to be able to check through a batch job if files in the directory adhere to this naming convention.

If filename is misspelled, i.e. `XX-TetsFiel.xlsx`, `XX` is not a digit like `02` or even `XX-testfile.xlsx` (all lowercase), then files should move to an Error directory.

I am using below to move the files to achieve this. I am testing with `11-testFiel.xlsx` but when I execute the .bat nothing happens - I get no errors and the file remains where it was before:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.xlsx | findstr /v "[0-9][0-9]-TestFile.xlsx"') do move "%%a" "C:\Temp\Archive\Error"
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The pipe symbol `|` has to be escaped with a caret `^|` inside a for /f command. If you'd executed the batch in an open cmd window you would see the error message.

Comment: @LotPings: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: You need to escape `|` with the batch file escape character, the caret (`^`), so it will become `^|`. This happens because `|` is executed in higher prio than the `for` loop.

Comment: @double-beep.. but LotPings already said that... why not just upvote his comment instead of repeating it?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard sorry, this is not a place to discuss that, but as you can see, I have added some explanations.

Comment: Related: [Batch script with for loop and pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6026773)

Comment: 'dir /b *.xlsx | findstr /v "[0-9][0-9]-TestFile.xlsx"' allows for 109 possible combinations since XX is a variable with two digits like 02. However, I would now only like to check for specific file names of 20 possible digits like 02-TestFile.xlsx, 05-TestFile.xlsx, 10-TestFile.xlsx, etc. This list is fixed...Can you suggest a solution for this?